# Don't see stack traces and system out print in server console. JBoss + Intellij Idea

Tags: logging, intellij-idea, jboss7.x

I extract jboss as in some folder.
Create new user.

In idea i add new server configuration: **jboss local**, create **war** artifact for deploy and run application. All seems ok, but i don't see error stack-traces and print in server console(or server log). How i can enable this for jboss(in tomcat work's fine)

Comment: Do you have a log4j configuration file in your WAR?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Yep, i open war and see configuration file in WEB-INF\log4j.properties

Comment: Final question, what version of JBoss, 7.1.1.Final?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins cat version.txt:
JBoss Enterprise Application Platform - Version 6.1.0.GA
From: https://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads/ : EAP built from AS 7.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false
```

solve my problem.

Comment: That option didn't work for me.  I'm using Wildfly 16 though.  Using that option results in warning in the console that the option is deprecated.  I thought checking the box in IntelliJ run configuration labeled "Show console when a message is printed to standard output stream" would work, but it doesn't.   Weird how printing "Hello World" to the console is so tricky with IntelliJ and Wildfly.

Comment: @Ryan According docs, name of property is changed in newer versions of WildFly http://docs.wildfly.org/16/Admin_Guide.html#per-deployment-logging. You have to use `use-deployment-logging-config` instead